# npm copyfiles without container folder

Tags: npm, npm-scripts, file-copying

I'm trying to use the NPM `copyfiles` package, which I used many times. But I'm trying to copy the content of a `dist` folder in a destination folder without creating a `dist` but I can't find the correct way of doing it. I basically just want the content of the `dist` (not the folder in itself).

So what I have is

`-- dist
   |
   -- bundles
   -- lib
   package.json`

I want this result

`-- destination
   |
   -- bundles
   -- lib
   package.json`

but I always get the `dist` in the destination which is unwanted

`-- destination
   |
   -- dist
      |
      -- bundles
      -- lib
      package.json`

I tried

```
cross-env copyfiles dist/**/*.* ../dest
```

I also tried with the `--up 1`

```
cross-env copyfiles --up 1 dist/**/*.* ../dest
```

The only thing that works is with the `-f` (flatten) flag but I lose the folder structure.

```
cross-env -f copyfiles dist/**/*.* ../dest
```

Am I missing something or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, given the examples shown in your question there is no need to use `copyfiles` with the additional package [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env). The package [copyfiles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles) will work cross platforms.

`cross-env` is used for setting and using environment variables, e.g. `NODE_ENV=production`.

Using the `--up 1` argument, (or its shorthand equivalent `-u 1`), with `copyfiles` is the correct way to omit the `dist` directory. So just use the following instead:

```
copyfiles --up 1 dist/**/*.* ../dest
```

I.e. remove the initial `cross-env` part to resolve the issue.

Comment: This is not working. It always brings in the source folder structure up to the path from which its being copied, in this case dist/ the question is how to drop the dist/.... from the destination folder. Makes no sense copying the source folder structure from which being copied (not the ones inside being copied, that is perfectly fine).

Comment: So in this case the dist/**/*.* is being copied as dest/dist/**/*.* what is required is dest/**.*

Answer (score 0):

Got this working with ncp npm package.

```
ncp ./dist/ dest --filter **/*.*
```